# Grouping validations to single button in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing a problem in my application that i have two buttons in my form, One is for to get registered and another is for logging in. I've 'required' attribute to form fields.My question is if i filled all fields in registration form and click 'Register' button,it doesn't do a postback and it is asking to fill 'login' fields also .My requirement is if i click 'Login' button it should fire only its required field validators and same to register button.How can i achieve this?  and how can i achieve to prevent post back in jquery..?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>


  <form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  Password: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
 <input type="button" value="Login" >

<br/>
<br/>
Firstname: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<br/>
 Password: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<br/>
 Email: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<br/>
 <input type="button" value="Register" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried something? can you show us some code?

Comment: <form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  Password: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
 <input type="button" value="Login" >


<br/>
<br/>
Firstname: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<br/>
 Email :   <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
<br/>
Password: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
 <input type="button" value="Register" >
</form>